# jquery ajax function undo not working as expected

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, ajax

I have a list of words, and want users to be able to click a button if they know a word, then this word will change to 'Known', the css class will change and the field `word_is_known` will change from `False` to `True`. But I also want the user to be able to undo this action. This seems to be working fine the first time, i.e. if the user clicks and then unclicks. But if the user clicks the same word again, it creates another entry into the `KnownWord` model instead of updating the existing one. I've been playing around with this endlessly, but can't figure it out.

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var known_words = 0;
  var clicked_words = [];
  var unclicked_words = [];
  $(".word_known").click(function() {
    var reference = this;
    var objectpk = $(this).data('objectpk');
    var userpk = $(this).data('userpk');
    $(this).toggleClass('increment');
    if ($(this).hasClass('increment')) {
    known_words++;
    clicked_words.push($(this).data('word'));
    add_object = 'add';
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: "/videos/songs/vocab/known/"+objectpk+"/"+userpk+"/",
      data: {'action': add_object, 'known_words': known_words, 'clicked_words': clicked_words},
      success: function(data) {
    $(reference).removeClass("btn-warning");
    $(reference).addClass("btn-success");
    $(reference).text("Known");
  },
      failure: function(data) {
        alert("There is an error!")
      },
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
      })
   console.log(known_words, clicked_words);
 }
  else {
  known_words--;
  unclicked_words.push($(this).data('word'));
  remove_object = 'remove';
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "/videos/songs/vocab/known-undo/"+objectpk+"/"+userpk+"/",
    data: {'action': remove_object, 'known_words': known_words, 'unclicked_words': unclicked_words},
    success: function(data) {
  $(reference).removeClass("btn-success");
  $(reference).addClass("btn-warning");
  $(reference).text("Yes");
},
    failure: function(data) {
      alert("There is an error!")
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    })
 console.log(known_words, unclicked_words);
}
})
});
```

My views:

```
def word_known(request, object_pk, pk_user):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'GET' and request.GET['action'] == 'add':
        known_words = request.GET.get('known_words', '')
        clicked_words = request.GET.getlist('clicked_words[]')
        request.session['known_words'] = known_words
        request.session['clicked_words'] = clicked_words
        user = request.user
        song = models.Song.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
        for word in set(clicked_words):
            models.KnownWord.objects.get_or_create(word_is_known=True,
            word=word, user=user, song=song)

    print('The number of known words is {} and clicked words are {}'.format(known_words, clicked_words))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(clicked_words), content_type='application/json')

def word_known_undo(request, object_pk, pk_user):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass

    elif request.method == 'GET' and request.GET['action'] == 'remove':
        known_words = request.GET.get('known_words', '')
        unclicked_words = request.GET.getlist('unclicked_words[]')
        request.session['known_words'] = known_words
        request.session['unclicked_words'] = unclicked_words
        user = request.user
        song = models.Song.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
        for word in set(unclicked_words):
            models.KnownWord.objects.filter(word=word,
                user=user, song=song).update(word_is_known=False)
    print('The number of known words is {} and deleted words are {}'.format(known_words, unclicked_words))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(unclicked_words), content_type='application/json')
```

The `KnownWord` model:

```
class KnownWord(models.Model):
    word_is_known = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="known_words", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

And the relevant part from my template:
....

```
  {% elif item.0 in known_words %}
    <a href="javascript:" class="word_known_undo btn btn-success btn-sm" data-word="{{item.0}}" data-objectpk="{{object_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Known</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="javascript:" class="word_known btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-word="{{item.0}}" data-objectpk="{{object_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Yes</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your problem here is you didn't remove the value from the other array
- Its all about arrays `push , check , splice` take a look at the next example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clicked_words = [] ;
  var unclicked_words = [];
  var known_words = 0;
  $(document).on('click' ,'.word_to_know:not(.pending)' , function(){   //<<<<<<<<<<< here
    var This = $(this);
    var This_data_word = This.data('word');
    This.addClass('pending').toggleClass('increment');
    if(This.hasClass('increment')){
      known_words++;
      clicked_words.push(This_data_word);
      unclicked_words = remove_if_in_array(unclicked_words , This_data_word);
      
      // inside ajax callback   //<<<<<<< here
      setTimeout(function(){ //<< don't use this .. this is just for the demo
       This.removeClass('pending');  // <<<<<<<< here
      } , 2000); //<< don't use this .. this is just for the demo
    }else{
      known_words--;
      unclicked_words.push(This_data_word);
      clicked_words = remove_if_in_array(clicked_words , This_data_word);
      
      // inside ajax callback   //<<<<<<< here
      setTimeout(function(){ //<< don't use this .. this is just for the demo
       This.removeClass('pending');  // <<<<<<<< here
      } , 2000); //<< don't use this .. this is just for the demo
    }
    
    console.log('known_words '+known_words);
    console.log('clicked_words [' +clicked_words +']');
    console.log('unclicked_words [' + unclicked_words+']');
  });

});

// remove value if is in the array
function remove_if_in_array(array , value){
  var index = array.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return array;
}

// update value if is in the array
function update_if_in_array(array , value){
  var index = array.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
  array.push(value);
  return array;
}
```

```css
a.increment{
  border : 1px solid #000;
  background : green;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:" class="word_to_know word_known_undo btn btn-success btn-sm" data-word="word_1_known" data-objectpk="{{object_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Known</a>

<a href="javascript:" class="word_to_know word_known_undo btn btn-success btn-sm" data-word="word_2_yes" data-objectpk="{{object_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Yes</a>
```

I make a single class for all `<a>` named it `word_to_know` you can change anything whatever you want .. But I hope you got the idea

Comment: I tried this and it's not working for me, though I'm sure I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: @MeL not working is not enough to describe programming problems .. Is the code works on the snippet but not in your own code? OR The code in the snippet is not what you want at all? And what exactly doesn't work with you??

Comment: Sorry. The snippet doesn't quite work the way I need to in my code. There is only one button, with the text changing depending on whether the word is known or not. I'm thinking that perhaps the error is not in my jquery but in my view? It seems that the object is not updating correctly and instead creating a new one.

Comment: When I use the code you provided, except for changing the class, it works exactly the way it did with my original code. If I use your new class then it doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: *then it doesn't work at all anymore* because you've to add the class `word_to_know` to your `<a>` in html as I mentioned in my answer @MeL

Comment: Yes, I did do that.

Comment: Ok @MeL you can forget all of that .. I added a function called `update_if_in_array` in my code .. add this function to your code and use `clicked_words = update_if_in_array(clicked_words , $(this).data('word'))`; instead of `clicked_words.push(..` line and the same thing for the `unclicked_words.push(..` and see what you'll get

Comment: I tried, but it's still creating duplicate words instead of updating the `word_is_known` field of the `KnownWord` model.

Comment: The strange thing is, my original code and your code work as expected as long as I don't click the button too quickly consecutively. But if I click and undo too many times (in the same session), then it doesn't work. Why would that be?

Comment: @MeL try to prevent click event while the code is in progress .. see my updated answer with class `pending`